# onTouch() method cancels the effect of ExpandableView of the groupItems

Tags: android, expandablelistview, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I have a class, named CustomAdapter, the method getGroupView() is from it. I have an ExpandableListView what I want to do, is: when I click a group item, it shows the children, like an ExpandableListView would act; if I press a group Item for a longer time, it opens a different activity.
    The problem is that, because of the OnTouchListener, now it wont show the children items on click, only on a longer press, it will access a different activity.
My solution was to return false in the OnTouch() method, but it does not work. Any ideas?

Note: I am pretty newbie in Android Development. Thanks :d

```
@Override

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewGroup getAct = parent;
    if(convertview == null)
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.explistgroupview, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.groupTextView);
    textView.setText(tables.get(groupPosition));
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.groupImageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus_sign);



    convertview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    duration += time;

                    if(duration >= MAX_DURATION) {
                        Context context = getAct.getContext();
                        i = new Intent(context, beer.class);
                        context.startActivity(i);

                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }


            }
            duration = 0;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return convertview;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hava two options in your issue.

1、

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                duration += time;
                if(duration <= MIN_DURATION){
                    // TODO: do onClick()
                    return true;
                }

                if(duration >= MAX_DURATION) {
                    Context context = getAct.getContext();
                    i = new Intent(context, beer.class);
                    context.startActivity(i);

                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
```

2、

```
convertview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                duration += time;

                if(duration >= MAX_DURATION) {
                    Context context = getAct.getContext();
                    i = new Intent(context, beer.class);
                    context.startActivity(i);

                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }


        }
        duration = 0;

        //next line has change
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can try it, but I'm not sure it can work nomal.

Comment: I made it work by using view.OnTouchListener(null), but only on x2 click.

Comment: You should know that if return value is true on onTouch method, touch event will be gone.

Comment: I tried your methods, the last does not work, and the first accesses the activity on click, but does not show the children in any way.

Comment: Posted it on an answer

Answer (score 0):

The getChildView :

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    tabelOrdersOnEachTable = (ArrayList<String>) tableOrders.get(groupPosition);
    TextView textView = null;
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.explistchildview, null);
textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(tabelOrdersOnEachTable.get(childPosition));

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("ChildClick", "Merge");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked on: " + tabelOrdersOnEachTable.get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```